How to write custom inference script when deploying TF2 models in sagemaker
I have a model trained in TF2 and was trying to deploy it using TensorFlowModel using sagemaker. When using the model, I also need to load other utilities, such as json to map inputs and a tokenizer (transformer) as well.
When using HuggingFace or SkLearn models, I could define a model_fn to load the model as well as the other utilities. How do I do this for TF2 models?
I have gone through the documentation but can't find a way to do so. I tried to add a model_fn to my custom inference script, but the script doesn't seem to invoke it.
Here is the code I am using
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import json

# Load the model
def model_fn(model_dir):
    """
    Load and return a TensorFlow SavedModel.
    Args:
        model_dir (str): The directory where the model is saved.
    Returns:
        A TensorFlow SavedModel.
    """
    model = tf.=.load_model(model_dir)
    return model

# Parse input data
def input_fn(input_data, content_type):
    """
    Deserialize the input data for the model.
    Args:
        input_data: The input data as received from the client.
        content_type: The MIME type of the input data.
    Returns:
        A numpy array to be passed to the model for inference.
    """
    if content_type == "application/json":
        input_dict = json.loads(input_data)
        return np.array(input_dict["instances"])
    elif content_type == "text/csv":
        return np.loadtxt(input_data.splitlines(), delimiter=",")
    else:
        raise ValueError(f"Unsupported content type: {content_type}")

# Handle preprocessing of inputs
def input_handler(data, context):
    """
    Process the request payload into the format required for `input_fn`.
    Args:
        data: The payload of the request.
        context: The context of the request, including content type.
    Returns:
        Preprocessed data for the model.
    """
    content_type = context.get_content_type()
    return input_fn(data.read().decode('utf-8'), content_type)

# Perform inference
def predict_fn(input_data, model):
    """
    Perform inference on the input data using the loaded model.
    Args:
        input_data: The preprocessed input data.
        model: The TensorFlow model.
    Returns:
        The raw predictions from the model.
    """
    predictions = model.predict(input_data)
    return predictions

# Serialize the output
def output_fn(prediction, accept):
    """
    Serialize the prediction output.
    Args:
        prediction: The raw prediction output from the model.
        accept: The requested MIME type of the response.
    Returns:
        The serialized response.
    """
    if accept == "application/json":
        response = {"predictions": prediction.tolist()}
        return json.dumps(response), "application/json"
    elif accept == "text/csv":
        response = "\n".join([",".join(map(str, row)) for row in prediction])
        return response, "text/csv"
    else:
        raise ValueError(f"Unsupported accept type: {accept}")

# Handle postprocessing of outputs
def output_handler(prediction, context):
    """
    Process the model's raw predictions into the response format.
    Args:
        prediction: The raw predictions from the model.
        context: The context of the response, including accept type.
    Returns:
        The formatted response.
    """
    accept = context.get_accept_header()
    response, content_type = output_fn(prediction, accept)
    context.set_response_content_type(content_type)
    return response




could you please share the steps to create and deploy the model on the endpoint?

I believe this is not possible, what i have done for this is to create my own inference script from scratch which uses Flask and defines the required endpoints. I was also having trouble downloading extra files using boto3, due to an issue with the TensorflowModel image.
